# how do I run php 5.4 code or earlier on php 5.5 server

Tags: php, lamp, downgrade

I just upgraded my Ubuntu server 12.x to 14.04, which upgraded the PHP to 5.5.9 - and now my core LAMP application doesn't work.

Is there a way to tweak my server's PHP settings, to serve up legacy PHP code? I think this is zend framework. I am not a PHP developer.

Comment: which kind of error do you have? cause if i remember correctly on php 5.5 short_tag get turned off by default, maybe can be the cause... if that's the case go /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and enable short tag, after that restart apache2 ^_^

Comment: "my core LAMP application doesn't work." Some error messages would be nice. As it stands your problem is too broad.

Comment: You can install a second (or third, fourth, fifth, etc.) version of PHP using [phpfarm](https://github.com/cweiske/phpfarm).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line

```
AddType x-httpd-php54 .php
```

to your `.htaccess` file

It's supported by most servers

Comment: you are a rockstar. You solved my problem! I can now see my system!!!! The PHP white screen of death has been overcome. Thank you for this suggestion, 4 years ago!!!